# Use an array as an argument in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

I am a bit new into programming and I have this function:

```
function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  json.forEach(function(val,idx,arr){
    if(val[key] == value){

      result.push(val)
    }
  })
```

My problem is the understanding of the second part:

```
json.forEach(function(val,idx,arr){
    if(val[key] == value){

      result.push(val)
    }
  })
```

We got in this case `val` as an argument and in the if statement we use the term `val[key]`. So does this means, the argument `val` is an array? And at the end, we push a whole array into the empty array named `result`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would fit better.

Comment: `const filterJSON = (json, key, value) => json.filter(val => val[key] === value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down:

`json.forEach(function(val,idx,arr){`

`forEach` takes a function. The first argument is one of the values from the thing being iterated over. The second and third arguments are the current index and the array itself, which you need if you want to mess around with the array while iterating through it.

In this case, the function will receive each of the things stored in the `json` object, one at a time.

`if(val[key] == value){`

`val` is an object. `val[key]` means "from `val`, get the property named `key`".

`result.push(val)`

If `val`'s `key` property was equal to the value we're filtering for, we push the `val` object into the list of things that gets returned.

I think the point of confusion is in the meaning of `val[key]`. The `[]` syntax is used both to index into an array (`arr[0]` gets the first thing in a list ) and to get a property of an object (`foo[bar]` gets `foo.bar`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `val` should be an array because `forEach()` is an array method.

> The forEach() method calls a provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

No, `push()` doesn't mean that the whole array will be pushed into `result`, but only the value inside the parentheses `()`.

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

Note: also remember to use `===` instead of `==` in JavaScript which was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/9358107).